# Insert incrementing number in non-auto incremental field and loop

Tags: php, mysql

If I have 50 tickets available, I need to insert 50 rows in to my ticket table that have the ticket ID, and label the ticket ID.

Data posted: EventID, TicketQTY

```
INSERT INTO Tickets (UserID, EventID, OrderID, TicketID)  VALUES (0,'$EventID',0, *AUTO INCREMENT NEEDED*)
```

Where it says Auto Increment Needed, I'd like this to insert rows 1 to whatever the TicketQTY is. For example if Ticket Quantity is 50, I need this to populate rows 1 - 50.

Ordinarily I would only populate these as needed, however I need these to update with user's details as they are ordered.

Comment: _“I need this to populate rows 1 - 50”_ - that is of course not what a simple single INSERT statement does. You will either need to execute single INSERTs in a loop then, or write a loop that adds as many entries in `VALUES(…)` as needed (for a multi insert statement.)

Comment: @CBroe that's what I'm struggling with. What is the most streamlined way of doing that along with the increasing the TicketID number? Is it a case of running a foreach loop and executing 50 times? Or is there a quicker way to insert them? Thanks

Comment: If you want to loop over a known integer range without any holes in it, then a `for` loop probably makes more sense. And if you don’t want to submit 50 individual INSERT statements, then create _one_ combined one having the form `VALUES( (…), (…) )` in your loop, and submit it to the database after.